# Does Azure's HTTP request timeout of 4 minutes apply to multipart-formdata file uploads?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

Azure apparently has a 4 minute timeout for http requests before they kill the connection. This is non configurable in app services:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/32b76114-67a4-4e6b-ac45-61b0f0a0829f/changing-the-4-minute-request-time-out-for-app-services?forum=AzureAPIApps

I have seen this first hand in my application - I have a process that allows users to view files that exist on a network drive, select a subset of those files and upload those files to a third party service. This happens via a post request which sends the list of file names using content-type json. This operation can take a while and I  receive a timeout error at almost exactly 4 minutes.

I also have another process which allows users to drag and drop files into the web application directly, these files are posted to the server using content-type multipart/form-data, and forwarded to the third party service. This request never times out no matter how long the upload takes.

Is there something about using multipart/form-data that overrides azures 4 minute timeout?

It probably does not matter but I am using Node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timeout is actually 3m 50s (230 seconds) and not 4 minutes.

But note that it is an **idle connection timeout**, meaning that it only kicks in if there is no data flowing in the request/response. So it is strange that you would hit this if you are actively uploading files. I would suggest monitoring network traffic to see if anything is being sent. If it really goes 230s with no uploaded data, then there is probably some other issue, and the timeout is just a side effect.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Note that I am only actively uploading files in my second scenario. In my first scenario I am simply posting a list of files to be uploaded - its the servers responsibility to communicate with the third party service and do the uploading. However from what your saying it sounds like it would be expected that my second scenario would work, since the client and the server are actively communicating.

Comment: @ManManWilly ok, I understand your first scenario now, and that will indeed cause a timeout. You'll need to move to some form of async pattern to fix this. i.e. an initial request starts the upload and returns, and subsequent requests check the status until it's complete.